# How to restart network wlan interface?

Tags: networking, interface

My wireless adapter loses connection after a while and only a reboot helps.

```
$ uname -a
Linux surveillance1 5.0.0-25-generic #26~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 1 13:51:34 UTC 2019 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux here

$ ip a
3: wls3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

$ ifconfig -a
wls3: flags=4098<BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    ether 00:00:00:00:00:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 523328  bytes 697266856 (697.2 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 257229  bytes 27152661 (27.1 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

$ lshw
  *-pci:1
         Beschreibung: PCI bridge
         Produkt: NM10/ICH7 Family PCI Express Port 2
         Hersteller: Intel Corporation
         Physische ID: 1c.1
         Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:00:1c.1
         Version: 02
         Breite: 32 bits
         Takt: 33MHz
         Fähigkeiten: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
         Konfiguration: driver=pcieport
         Ressourcen: irq:25 ioport:3000(Größe=8192) memory:ec000000-edffffff ioport:e4000000(Größe=1048576)
       *-network DEAKTIVIERT
            Beschreibung: Kabellose Verbindung
            Produkt: PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection
            Hersteller: Intel Corporation
            Physische ID: 0
            Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:03:00.0
            Logischer Name: wls3
            Version: 02
            Seriennummer: 00:00:00:00:00:00
            Breite: 32 bits
            Takt: 33MHz
            Fähigkeiten: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
            Konfiguration: broadcast=yes driver=iwl3945 driverversion=5.0.0-25-generic firmware=15.32.2.9 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
            Ressourcen: irq:31 memory:edf00000-edf00fff
```

i tryd

```
 $ sudo ifup wlan0
 error: cannot find interfaces: wlan0

 $sudo ifup wls3
 error: cannot find interfaces: wls3
```

dmesg (part of it)

```
$ dmesg

[20803.015155] wls3:  Failed check-sdata-in-driver check, flags: 0x4
[20803.015206] WARNING: CPU: 1 PID: 15470 at /build/linux-hwe-DU_X3C/linux-hwe-5.0.0/net/mac80211/driver-ops.h:19 drv_conf_tx+0x160/0x1b0 [mac80211]
[20803.015207] Modules linked in: btrfs zstd_compress xor raid6_pq ufs qnx4 hfsplus hfs minix ntfs msdos jfs xfs libcrc32c cpuid hid_generic usbhid hid pci_stub vboxpci(OE) vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) binfmt_misc arc4 snd_hda_codec_analog snd_hda_codec_generic coretemp snd_hda_intel iwl3945 snd_hda_codec kvm iwlegacy snd_hda_core irqbypass thinkpad_acpi pcmcia snd_hwdep input_leds nvram mac80211 snd_pcm serio_raw ledtrig_audio yenta_socket snd_seq_midi lpc_ich pcmcia_rsrc snd_seq_midi_event pcmcia_core snd_rawmidi snd_seq snd_seq_device snd_timer cfg80211 snd soundcore mac_hid sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp parport ip_tables x_tables autofs4 crypto_simd cryptd aes_i586 algif_skcipher af_alg dm_crypt i915 i2c_algo_bit drm_kms_helper syscopyarea psmouse firewire_ohci ahci sysfillrect libahci firewire_core pata_acpi sysimgblt fb_sys_fops sdhci_pci e1000e cqhci crc_itu_t sdhci drm video
[20803.015250] CPU: 1 PID: 15470 Comm: kworker/1:0 Tainted: G        W  OE     5.0.0-25-generic #26~18.04.1-Ubuntu
[20803.015251] Hardware name: LENOVO 17045UG/17045UG, BIOS 7BETC7WW (2.08 ) 03/07/2007
[20803.015284] Workqueue: events_freezable ieee80211_restart_work [mac80211]
[20803.015318] EIP: drv_conf_tx+0x160/0x1b0 [mac80211]
[20803.015320] Code: 8d 65 f4 89 f8 5b 5e 5f 5d c3 8b 55 ec 8b 8a ec 02 00 00 81 c2 fc 02 00 00 50 85 c9 0f 45 d1 52 68 74 6d 97 f8 e8 00 f0 77 d3 <0f> 0b 83 c4 0c 8d 65 f4 bf fb ff ff ff 89 f8 5b 5e 5f 5d c3 8d 74
[20803.015322] EAX: 00000035 EBX: f2c41982 ECX: f75e8680 EDX: 00000007
[20803.015324] ESI: f2c41580 EDI: 00000003 EBP: df34dbac ESP: df34db8c
[20803.015326] DS: 007b ES: 007b FS: 00d8 GS: 00e0 SS: 0068 EFLAGS: 00010296
[20803.015328] CR0: 80050033 CR2: 0061fb60 CR3: 31cf0000 CR4: 000006f0
```

Comment: From the terminal, please try: `sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*` and tell us if there is any improvement.

Comment: nope, unfortunately nothing happens  :/

Comment: "nothing happens" is the expected behavior. It means that the command was executed as requested and that there are no errors or warnings to report. What I am asking is if there is any change to the wireless losing connection.

Comment: `$ iw dev wls3 get power_save`

`Power save: off`


ok i will monitor it and report

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you've applied all of the current Ubuntu software updates, you might try updating your BIOS. It may, or may not, fix your current problem.

**Note: backup your important files first!**

You have BIOS version 7BETC7WW (V2.08) 03/07/2007.

The current version appears to be 29CN38WW (V2.15) 13 Feb 2011.

**Note: Verify this BIOS information at the lenovo web site by using your model #**

Go to https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds008568 to download the newer version. Installation instructions are also there.

Comment: i maybe give it a try =)
thx

Comment: @p.harz status please...